# Delete text form text file using Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, text-files

How can I delete from a text file in Winforms?

My aim is to delete a selected text from a text box and it can also be deleted in my text file.

Specifically, my need is that if the user delete the text from a text box it also be deleted from text file.

My code is:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
        of.ShowDialog();
        textBox1.Text = of.FileName;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text);
        textBox2.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(textBox1.Text, true);
        sw.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
        sw.Close();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.SelectedText = "";
        string selectedText = "theTextYouWantToDelete";
        string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\demo\demo.txt");
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\demo\demo.txt", 
  fileContent.Replace(selectedText, ""));
    }

    private bool SelectedText(char arg)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: You mean delete the content of a text file? Your question is unclear, and that code won't compile

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to achieve. Could you please provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: @Innat3 I mean that how I can delete a selected text from a text file using delete button

Comment: Read the text into a string (assuming the file isn't too big), then do a replace (to replace the string with `""` (i.e. empty string) and then overwrite the file with the new version of the string.

Comment: you have to save the new file... so reading it all again wont help.. you meant to write the newtext to the file

Comment: @ADyson could you please show me what are you trying to say my need is how I can deleted selected text from a text file while it appears in a text box

Comment: @SyedTaha Not sure what you mean "while it appears in a text box"? Do you want the user to be able to manually edit the whole file? Or you just want the user to type the text to be replaced, and then the program should find that text in the file and remove it? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: @ADyson my need is that if the user delete the text from a text box it also be deleted from text file

Comment: Ok so if the whole content of the file is in the textbox, and the user has changed that content, it sounds like quite simply you must take the content of the textbox and write it to the file, ensuring you make it overwrite everything which was in the file previously. It should not be complicated. Innat's answer and comments below can guide you on doing it.

Comment: @ADyson yes but I can find right coding for it

Comment: @ADyson my problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand it, you should simply be able to write

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
  File.WriteAllText(@"C:\demo.txt", textBox2.Text, "")); 
}
```

This will replace the contents of your file with the current contents of the textbox. Assuming the user has already deleted the needed text from the textbox, it should work correctly.

See the [documentation for File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8) fore more info.

Comment: @SyedTaha no problem. If the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as "accepted" - click on the tick mark next to the question so it turns green. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will replace the `selectedText` with an empty string

```
string selectedText = textBox2.Text;
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\demo.txt");
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\demo.txt", fileContent.Replace(selectedText, ""));
```

Comment: @SyedTaha then you're doing something wrong, update your question's code for us to see

Comment: I have posted my full code can you please gudie me on this

Comment: @SyedTaha try replacing `textBox2.SelectedText = "";
        string selectedText = "theTextYouWantToDelete";` with `string selectedText = textBox2.Text;`